# Text alignment issue

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

guys i have a problem trying to get two texts stick to the left and right of a container

I use the following

```
<h4>Better Tri-Blend T-Shirt</h4>
<span  style="float: right ">£4 </span>
```

This looks like this

[image]

As you can see it works sorta with both aligned to left and right but the font size on the right is smaller than the left and not the same

How do I make the right font bigger (eg h4) or even bigger

I have tried covering in a h4 but that knocks out the right alignment

Amy help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

**Heading**(`h1, h2, h3..`) are block elements, which means that they occupy full width.

Their font sizes are fixed and are defined by the browser, unless overridden by style-sheets.

To make 2 or more heading align with each other, make them  `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`

Optionally you can use `vertical-align:middle;` to vertically center them if they are of different sizes.

```css
h4,h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Better Tri-Blend T-Shirt</h4>
  <h4>£4 </h4>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
  <h4>Better Tri-Blend T-Shirt</h4>
  <h2 style="float:right">£4 </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Gautam you're a star the 2nd div worked exactly as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Simply insert the span inside the h4:

```html
<h2>Better Tri-Blend T-Shirt<span style="float:right; ">£4</span></h2>
```